# Tooltip issue in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want dynamic text tool tip for input box and i have used bootstrap 3.1.1 here with angularjs 1.2.16

but i am getting value as undefined through ng-model of input box.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="searchColumnOfDatagridQuery1" placeholder="Search {{columnData[0].text.toLowerCase()}} here" tooltip="Search {{columnData[0].text.toLowerCase()}} here" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-append-to-body="true">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" ng-click="searchColumnOfDatagrid(searchColumnOfDatagridQuery1,1)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </span>  
    </div>
```

**JSFiddle**
I have update my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PYjZp/)

Can any one tell me why i am not getting ng-model value here and how to resolve this issue?

How to get ng-model value of text-box because on click of button i am getting undefined value?

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: @aamir sajjad: My problem is i am not getting ng-model value of text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found workaround for this [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/577)

you can change value of your `ng-model` attribute from `searchColumnOfDatagridQuery1` to: `$parent.searchColumnOfDatagridQuery1` and it should works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

$.parent.Whatevermodel property you have is the solution. Please check following plunkr, it is working for me.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cnm0pGYXBHda4I5hpYYi?p=preview

Upvote and accept it as answer if it helps:)

Comment: How to get ng-model value of text-box because on click of button i am getting undefined value?

Comment: @Sachin Kumbharkar I have update my answer. Please check it now